# Right to left slide toggle with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

How to make a mini cart toggle with jquery? I had that bag link on the right corner, when I clicked it, it will slide the hidden `div` containing mini cart info that will slide from right ( not visible before ) to left ( visible after click ) and then had overlay background for the rest of the page. Ignoring the cart content, it will do with php, just need the div slide animate with jquery,

```
<div class="container">
<div id="pollSlider-button"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"><div class="pollSlider"></div></div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function()
{
   var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"> </div>');
  $('#pollSlider-button').click(function() {
    if($(this).css("margin-right") == "200px")
    {
        $('.pollSlider').animate({"margin-right": '-=200'});
        $('.right').css("position", 'relative');
        $('#pollSlider-button').animate({"margin-right": '-=200'});
        overlay.appendTo('.left')
    }
    else
    {
        $('.pollSlider').animate({"margin-right": '+=200'});
        $('#pollSlider-button').animate({"margin-right": '+=200'});
        $('.right').css("position", 'relative');
        overlay.appendTo('.left')
    }


  });
 });    

.pollSlider{
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    width:200px;
    right:0px;
    margin-right: -200px;
}
#pollSlider-button{
    position:fixed;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    right:0px;
    background:green;
    top:300px;
}
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 10000;
}
.container {
     width: 100%;
}
.left {
    width: 80%;
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
}
.right { 
    width: 20%;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[image: Cart Link]

[image: Cart Toggle]

Comment: please post your code for toggle.

Comment: For animation from right try http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ FadeInRight effect. You will need a little javascript for background overlay.

Comment: no distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)), thanks are never part of good question, spell checking is.

Comment: updated at question @maxspan

Comment: Thanks @anthon, i updated with code